# How to create a batch file to calling an action in PHP symfony 1.4

Tags: php, batch-file, symfony-1.4

I need to do a action: Remind user update Résumé every 2 months via email. I wrote code for this, when I open URL:

localhost/orangehrm/symfony/web/index.php/pim/sendEmailReminder, it worked, user can receive email successfully.

Now I need to use Task Scheduler to call this action daily, a write a batch file with following content:

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f "C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm\symfony\plugins\orangehrmPimPlugin\modules\pim\actions\sendEmailReminderAction.class.php".
```

I checked with cmd and it did NOT work. Error was seen:

```
C:\Users\tthnhan.TMA\Desktop>C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm\symfony\plugins\orangehrm
PimPlugin\modules\pim\actions\sendEmailReminderAction.class.php

C:\Users\tthnhan.TMA\Desktop>C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm\s
ymfony\plugins\orangehrmPimPlugin\modules\pim\actions\sendEmailReminderAction.cl
ass.php

Fatal error: Class 'sfActions' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm\symfony\pl
ugins\orangehrmPimPlugin\modules\pim\actions\sendEmailReminderAction.class.php o
n line 14

Call Stack:
0.0090     132088   1. {main}() C:\xampp\htdocs\orangehrm\symfony\plugins\or
angehrmPimPlugin\modules\pim\actions\sendEmailReminderAction.class.php:0
```

Can somebody help me about this? How to call an action which has extended to Symfony class in batch file?

Below is my sendEmailReminderAction.class.php file:

```
class sendEmailReminderAction extends sfActions {

//put your code here

public function execute($request) {

    $emailService = new EmailService();
    $employeeService = new EmployeeService();

    $employeeTable = $employeeService->getEmployeeList();

    foreach ($employeeTable as $employee) {
        $lastUpdate = $employee->getLast_update();
        $today = date("Y-m-d");
        $datetime1 = date_create($lastUpdate);
        $datetime2 = date_create($today);
        $interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);            
        $result = $interval->format('%R%a');

        if($result >= +60) {
            $empName = $employee->getFirstName();
            $empEmail = $employee->getEmpWorkEmail(); 

            $datetime1->add(new DateInterval('P67D'));              
            $deadline =  $datetime1->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";

            $emailService->sendEmailUpdateCV($empEmail, $empName, $lastUpdate, $deadline);

        }
    }

    exit;
}

}
```

Thanks so much,

Answer (score 0):

You should create symfony command instead of a action.

this may help you.

http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/13-Leveraging-the-Power-of-the-Command-Line

Comment: Thanks so much, onlybj. I will try with this.